# Database Migration from Oracle RAC to AWS Amazon Aurora

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, oracle-rac

I am working on a task to make a data migration plan to migrate Oracle RAC to AWS Amazon Aurora.
The current in-house production database is based on a 10TB, 8 Node Oracle RAC Cluster with single node
standby in DR site. The database has 2 main schemas, comprising of 500 tables, 300 Packages and Triggers, 20 Partitioned tables, 5000 concurrent session of which 100 are active at a given time and has an IOPS requirement of 50K read and 30K write IOPS. The development database is 1/10th of the production capacity.

I did research and found that DMS (Data Migration Service) and SCT (Schema Conversion Tool) takes care of all the migration process. So do we need to work on any individual specifications mentioned in the task or will DMS and SCT take care of the whole migration process?

Answer (score 4):

The tools you mention (DMS and SCT) are powerful and useful, but will they take care of the whole migration process?  Very unlikely unless you have a very simple data model.

There will likely be some objects and code that cannot be converted automatically and will need manual input/development from you. Migrating a database is usually not a simple thing and even with tools like SCT and DMS you need to be prepared to plan, review and test.

SCT can produce an assessment report for you. I would start here.  Your question is next to impossible to answer on a forum like this without intricate knowledge of the system you are migrating.

Comment: Thanks for the response @smbennett1974. I know that Database Migration is not a simple task. As per the specifications of database I have mentioned, can you share some sources which I can refer to plan a migration?